# What happens to reputation after 200 daily limit?

Tags: support, reputation

Today is the first time I have earned more than 200 reputation in one day.  200 is the daily limit. However, I am still earning reputation. Currently I have an Accept and 5+ answer Up-votes that are not  being counted in reputation history.

What happens to this uncounted reputation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/7238):

> You can earn a maximum of +200 reputation from upvotes and suggested edits in any given [day](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27199). Bounties and the bonuses for accepted answers are counted separately ([source](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/03/the-great-reputation-recalc-begins/)). Reputation "lost" from the reputation cap is not awarded on following days.

At the very least, you'll get a "Mortarboard" badge since it's your first time to hit the rep cap.

Comment: :-(  Aww, man.  All that rep is going to waste.  Any idea why this was implemented?

Comment: @Edmund, have a look at [this meta.SE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22447) thread.

Comment: I see.  Gaming the system and the like.  It doesn't make it hurt any less. Perhaps as your rep increases so too should your daily cap. `Piecewise[{{200, x < 5000}, {300, x < 15000}, {400, True}}]`

Comment: You get used to it. Have a look at the Wizard's reputation history, for instance. Or, for that matter, everybody with a "Legendary" badge.

Comment: @J.M. I *am* everybody with a Legendary badge. ;^)   http://i.stack.imgur.com/pConc.png

Comment: @Edmund according to my `/reputation` page I have had about 3,000 *votes* (not reputation points) that did not count because of the cap, with a stinging 63 of those happening on September 6th 2013! (Check if you want.)  It's just part of the game here, as is reputation itself of course.  I do sometimes think that "lost" reputation would better serve the community in the form of bounties, but I suppose top contributors already have enough influence without playing Santa Claus too, and I think the developers in their wisdom realized that.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard http://m.memegenerator.net/instance/55199488

Comment: @YvesKlett Unfortunately I am getting a "The page isn't redirecting properly" from that, which is a shame as I am hoping it is something funny.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard eek,  strange that,  works for me. Not a big intellectual  miss though,  just google "legendary meme". Long week here,  so that might excuse the whimsy .